# how to add two numbers in typescript using interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, frontend, typescript2.0

here I'm trying to add two numbers using typescript interfaces and arrow functions concept. when I'm running the compiled js code it is calling add() method and it is displaying NaN.

below is the ts code:-
    var add = (Num) =>  console.log(Num.num1 + Num.num2) ;

```
interface Num {
num1: number;
num2: number;
}

this.add(1,2);
```

below is the js code:-

```
var add = function (Num) { return console.log(Num.num1 + Num.num2); };
this.add(1, 2);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

## Root Cause: No Type Annotation

While other answers solve the symptom, I don't believe they have addressed the underlying problem in your code, which is here:

```
var add = function (Num) { return console.log(Num.num1 + Num.num2); };
```

The parameter here is *called* `Num`, and has no *type*. I believe you intended this to be:

```
//                   name: type
const add = function (num: Num) { return console.log(num.num1 + num.num2); };
```

## Calling Add

Your code isn't in a particular context, so let's drop `this` for a second and look at the call to the `add` function:

```
// ERROR: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
// const add: (num: Num) => void
add(1, 2);
```

TypeScript is now helping you to see the error in your call. Solving the call to `add` without solving your root cause fixed the symptom, but not the underlying issue.

You can now update your call to add with:

```
add({ num1: 1, num2: 2 });
```

And it will work - but so will all future calls; because your `add` function now had type information.

## Demo

Drop the following into a TypeScript file, or the TypeScript Playground, to see this in action:

```
interface Num {
    num1: number;
    num2: number;
}

const add = function (num: Num) { return console.log(num.num1 + num.num2); };

add(1, 2);

add({ num1: 1, num2: 2 });
```

## add(1, 2)

If you want to have an add method that allows the signature `add(1, 2)` you need to change the signature... the fully annotated function itself can be described as:

```
const add = function (a: number, b: number): number {
    return a + b
};
```

If you want to see what the interface looks like for this, it is below:

```
interface Adder {
    (num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

const add: Adder = function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

## Super Add

If you want your `add` function to handle more numbers, you can use a rest parameter... like this:

```
const add = function (...numbers: number[]) {
    if (!numbers || !numbers.length) {
        return 0;
    }    

    return numbers
        .reduce(function (acc, val) {
            return acc + val;
        });
};

console.log(add());

console.log(add(1, 2));

console.log(add(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

This will handle any number of arguments.

Comment: when I call add method as add(1,2) it is giving error but add({ num1: 1, num2: 2 }); is working. but I don't want to call it using the second method because for example when I have the 10 arguments for the add function then we should pass 10 arguments while calling the function. then using interface no sense here. I just want to call add method like this add(1,2) and should implement interface concept.

Comment: @ganesh - I have added an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

You defined a function `add()` that accept a parameter of type Num, but you're actually passing it two number, not a Num.
So simply change your call to

```
add({num1: 1, num2: 2});
```

which is an object with the props you want.
Hope it helps

Comment: it is working..but if we call the add method like you said then what is the use of interface here, we can also call add method using add(1,2). but I want to implement interface here so that if I have the more number of arguments i will define all the variables in one interface I can simply send that interface to the function as an argument. but if i follow your process i should pass all the variables on function calling.....

Answer (score 1):

`this.add({ num1: 1, num2: 2 });` - that is the point.

In your code you pass two params (1 and 2), function expects only one (Num). So you have to pass values as Num object.